# Get instantiated UIElement of ContentTemplate from TabControl

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datatemplate, tabcontrol, contentpresenter

I have a `TabControl` where the `ContentTemplate` is defined by a `DataTemplate` containing a `ContentPresenter`. The mapping `UIElement` class is defined by a `DataTemplate` for the specific ViewModel type. It works like that:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:DiagramVM}">
            <Controls:Diagram DataContext="{Binding}" x:Name="diagram"/>
        </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Tabs, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedTabIndex}"
                            x:Name="AnalysisTabCtrl" Template="{DynamicResource ScrollableTabControlTemplate}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Header}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=ViewModel}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
 </TabControl>
```

My problem is that I need the instance of the instantiated UIElements. In this case the *Diagram* instances. How can I get them?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`ItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainergenerator.aspx) to get a `TabItem` out of your `TabControl`, then you can use [`FindName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname.aspx) on the [`TabItem.ContentTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplate.aspx) to search for named instantiated controls. (Here you would probably need to name the content-presenter and then again search in its `ContentTemplate`)

I would not recommend doing anything like that, if you cannot manage without this you probably did not bind all the relevant properties to your items.